# Integer overflow detected on your platform

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to list all the documents I have inside a MongoDB collection, but I keep receiving this error:

> MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Integer overflow
>   detected on your platform: 1000000000 in (...):16 Stack trace: #0
>   {main}

I think that I'm receiving this error because the following value is too big to be an integer.

My code:

```
try {

        $mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('...');

        $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);

        $rows = $mongo->executeQuery('..', $query);    

        echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($rows));


    } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {


      echo $e;
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: How much documents you have in the collection?

Comment: Only 4, each one has 9 fields, and I'm receiving this error because of a field that I use to insert epoch values to be converted later. The type of this field is Int64.

Comment: which PHP build do you using (32-bit or 64-bit) ?

Comment: I'm using the 32bit, maybe it should work with 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you working with 64-bit int then your PHP also should be 64-bit (-;

Answer (score 0):

actually you trying to get all the content which is consuming large amount of memory you should make a chunks.
[see this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646193/mongodb-driver-exception-invalidargumentexception-integer-overflow-detected-on-y)